# find element id Which is combined with the number jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery ajax request return in tables with specify id

`"<tbody id=\"movePlace/"+newDay.Id+"\">"+` in resualt (resualt is ex:`<tbody id="movePlace/e5ecc5b0-4812-e811-9c25-50e549387d78"></tbody>`),

in an other ajax request 
i need put result in above id ,so i wrote this :

```
done(function(result) {
                    $('body').find('#movePlace/' + currentDayIdClicked).append(result);
                });
```

note:`currentDayIdClicked` is id number(Guid)

But nothing happens,Where is the mistake?

Comment: Use `'#movePlace\\/' + currentDayIdClicked`. However I would recommend you to remove `/` from ID when creating element

Comment: What does `$('body').find('#movePlace/' + currentDayIdClicked).length;` return? (and why prefix it with `"movePlace/"`?)

Comment: it depends how you are making ajax request, seccond sould be after completion of first request

Comment: @Satpal is The answer is right

Comment: @StephenMuecke after change` '#movePlace\\/' + currentDayIdClicked` return 1 and work find

Comment: Yes I know, but why are you over-complicating this by adding the `movePlace/` prefix? - All you need to your the `Guid` value as the `id`

Comment: i have many tables with many Move in tables for server side i need to detect  for add to database

Comment: Then it would be better to use `<tbody id="yourGuid" class="movePlace">` and `$('body').find('.movePlace#' + yourGuid)`. And do not add answers in the question (I have rolled back your changes). Add your answer in the Answers section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first answer is with the current structure

> Use '#movePlace\/' + currentDayIdClicked. However I would recommend
>   you to remove / from ID when creating element   – Satpal

The second answer to the new structure and delete / character

> Then it would be better to use `<tbody id="yourGuid" class="movePlace">`
>   and $('body').find('.movePlace#' + yourGuid) –
>   Stephen Muecke